# What is Lifecycle that we call function in react state?

Tags: reactjs

When  we call  function in react state  such a
state={

student:getstudent()

}

this function does  run in which lifecycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://itnext.io/react-understanding-state-lifecycle-d45df5d2cf3f) state is initialized before any of the lifecycle methods run. Therefore, the `getstudent()` is not ran in any of the lifecycle methods, it is ran before them.

This code can help you visualize it:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: console.log("State")
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>test</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes  it's  right so  i named  it  pre render. i test    and debug  and  I recognize  it  run  before  all  them ,,,,,,  even constructor!!!